# How to get all xtype values from a window

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Let's say I have a window which are several combobox's and texfield's. What I want to do, getting all selected and filled values from this window to be able to post server side.

I used to ComponentQuery but only getting specified type of field. Is there any solution to get any kind of xtype values, like combobox, checkbox, textfield etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use an Ext.form.Panel, it contains functionality to manage groups of fields:

```
var win = new Ext.window.Window({
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        border: false,
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [] // your fields here
    }
});
// Later
console.log(win.down('form').getForm().getValues());
```

Comment: thanks Evan, I have last question. I have also defined several windows out of Form Panel. Those windows also has xtype's. How can I get those windows xtype fields?

Comment: The same way. Use forms, don't try and roll your own solution. It's built into the framework.